# Unable to write to Excel row

Tags: c#, excel

I want simply write something to specific cell, but my approach works only for the first column of my Excel sheet.

```
for (int c = 1; c < 30; c++)
{
 if (secondWorksheet.Cells[2, c].Value.ToString() == functions.ObtainTranslation(lclp))
  {
     secondWorksheet.Cells[CurrentRow, c].Value = ReadFromLine(reader.LineNumber, "value", 
     "value_nt");
  }
}
```

Whenever I would set column to more then `1`, debugger throws an exception `Row out of range`.

The problem occurs only when I am writing.

Comment: What's the value of CurrentRow?

Comment: @d4zed That can be between 9 and 9000, but in my testing case, it is 69

Comment: Put a break point on that line and check the value of `CurrentRow` and `c`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Weird, I can't see CurrentRow in the list of variables, how is that possible?

Comment: It is declared like: public int CurrentRow = 1;, and then it is supposed to change to whatever between 9 and 9000, I must check that!

Comment: I don't see CurrentRow in breakpointing

Comment: What exactly is the exception, is it an Office exception or a .net exception for the reader?

Comment: Set the value before `for (int c = 1; c < 30; c++)` and increment it inside the `IF`

Comment: Ususally the data is written after the last row (Will be 1 if there is no data). Should you not be trying to find that first rather than setting/hardcoding it's value?

Comment: Hello again, I have solved this by redesining my code, thank you for help anyway.